# Configuring Email Forwarding with GoDaddy (Microsoft 365) and Mailgun Simultaneously

Tags: mailgun, godaddy-api

I'm currently using a regular email account hosted with GoDaddy, specifically Microsoft 365. I want to explore the possibility of setting up email forwarding through Mailgun while still maintaining the existing GoDaddy email setup.

- is it feasible to have a regular email account on GoDaddy (Microsoft 365) alongside an email forwarding configuration through Mailgun?
- Are there any potential conflicts or issues that might arise from having these two email configurations simultaneously?
- What steps should I take to set up email forwarding through Mailgun while keeping my primary email hosted on GoDaddy?

Any insights, experiences, or guidance on achieving this dual email setup would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Try on https://serverfault.com/ . Not a programming question